# Django intermediate model

Tags: django

I m trying to construct a relationship that would woud  allow multiple entities give regular updates on a project. To be more precise i want to define the terms used in the model.

Lead => This would be the project.

Company => Contractor(s) that would be allowed to bid on the project. While bidding/negotiation on the project they have to regularly update status field for the lead.

Lead update => Table used to keep the updates.

But when i try to run the server i get this error

```
"companies.leadupdate: Reverse query name for field 'lead' clashes with m2m field 'Lead.leadupdate'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'lead'"
```

I decided to go this route based on the example on Django site https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/ which is similar to what i m trying to achieve.I may be completely off as well :)

```
from django.db import models
class Company(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comp_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comp_email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comp_zip = models.IntegerField()
    comp_phone = models.IntegerField()
    comp_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comp_name



class Leadsource(models.Model):
    assetname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.assetname


class Lead(models.Model):

    numberofstations = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    #company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    leadsource = models.ForeignKey(Leadsource)
    submissiondate = models.DateField('Submission Date')
    cname = models.CharField('Business Name', max_length=100)
    crep = models.CharField('Principle Contact', max_length=100)
    cemail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    caddress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    leadupdate = models.ManyToManyField(Company,through='Leadupdate')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s %s" % (self.cname, self.crep, self.leadsource)


class Leadupdate(models.Model):
    updatedate = models.DateField()
    update = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    updatefrom = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u" %s - %s " % (self.update, self.updatedate)
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says try to add related_name argument to definition of Lead field, e.g.:

```
lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, related_name="lead_related")
```

This should solve the problem.